# how to display top heap allocations grouped by stack?

Tags: memory-leaks, heap-memory, windbg

I have a dump of a process that was running with user-stack-traces flag on. I am trying to analyze a leak from WinDbg. Using instructions [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31382/Memory-Leak-Detection-Using-Windbg) I am able to see top allocations grouped by allocation sizes, list all allocations with specific size, display stack of an allocation using allocation address.

Is there a way to display top allocations grouped by stack? (By 'top' I mean highest contributors to total heap size or total allocation count.) All the information is already in the dump, I just need the right WinDbg extension. I would be surprised if no one wrote such an extension so far.

Comment: You may want to look at "Announcing Tracer: A Generic Way to Track Resource Usage and Leaks" http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2013/09/10/announcing-tracer-a-generic-way-to-track-resource-usage-and-leaks.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+sashag+%28All+Your+Base+Are+Belong+To+Us%29

Comment: It's a valid idea, but using breakpoints kills performance, whereas the performance of +ust flags is usually tolerable.